# Order wp_list_comments by popularity

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have a plugin to add a 'like' to a comment, each 'like' is stored in a table called `likes_comments`, I'm trying to sort the output of `wp_list_comments` according to how many likes each comment has, I'd like the comment with the most likes to appear at the top.

Here's what I'm using to call `wp_list_comments`:

```
<?php global $wp_query;
    $comment_arr = $wp_query->comments; usort($comment_arr, 'comment_comparator');
    wp_list_comments('callback=my_callback', $comment_arr);
?>
```

And here's my function:

```
function comment_comparator($a, $b)
{
$compared = 0;
if($a->likes_comments != $b->likes_comments)
{
    $compared = $a->likes_comments < $b->likes_comments ? 1:-1;
}
return $compared;
}
if($a->likes_comments == 0)
{
$compared = $compared2;
}
```

I'm completely stuck with this, any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order this to work, place the code in `functions.php` **AND** in and in `comments.php` (you need to find the exact placement location, before calling `wp_list_comments()` in `comments.php`):

**functions.php:**

```
function comment_comparator($a, $b)
    {
        $compared = 0;
        if($a->comment_karma != $b->comment_karma)
        {
            $compared = $a->comment_karma < $b->comment_karma ? 1:-1;
        }
        return $compared;
        }
```

**comments.php:**

```
global $wp_query;
    $comment_arr = $wp_query->comments;
    usort($comment_arr, 'comment_comparator');
    wp_list_comments('callback=gtcn_basic_callback', $comment_arr);
```

Important note: This procedure is valid when using the plug-in [comments rating](http://wealthynetizen.com/comment-rating-pro/) (thumbs up - thumbs down). Read additional info [here](http://www.theunusableweb.com/tips/coding/php-coding/wordpress/re-order-wordpress-comments/).

Comment: It works, however when I do this the posts with the same karma get ordered by the oldest first. How to solve this?

Comment: This can be solved by using `'reverse_top_level=true'` and/or `'reverse_children=true'` in function `wp_list_comments()`. Setting this to true will display the most recent comment first then going back in order and will display the children (reply level comments) with the most recent ones first, then going back in order.